# PHP Web Service Client: Passing NULL parameter

Tags: php, web-services

I'm attempting to pass a string to my "start" method via a simple web service client.  Even though I've set the value of "prefix", which "start" is looking for, it still continues to pass only a NULL value.

This is the returned output:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["processId"]=> string(6) "701019" } 
string(304) "701019" 

string(258) " " //THIS IS WHERE I SHOULD SEE 'GenesisID'
```

Code is below.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require_once('nusoap.php');

$client = new SoapClient('C:\wsdl\BenefitDeterminationProcess_BenefitDialogueServiceSOAP.wsdl', array('trace' => 1));


$param = array("prefix"=>'GenesisID:');

$result = $client->__soapCall('start',
        array(new SoapParam('prefix', 'GenesisID')),
        array('soapaction' => 'C:\wsdl\BenefitDeterminationProcess_BenefitDialogueServiceSOAP\start'));

$respXML = $client->__getLastResponse();
$requXML = $client->__getLastRequest();

var_dump($result);
echo "<p>";
var_dump($respXML);
echo "<p>";
var_dump($requXML);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "GenesisID" is supposed to be your value, then you have used the SoapParam constructor in a wrong way.

From the PHP Manual:

```
SoapParam::__construct ( mixed $data , string $name )
```

So the constructor call should be:

```
new SoapParam('GenesisID', 'prefix')
```

Comment: GenesisID is the value I expect to be passed, but even when switching prefix and GenesisID in the SoapParam, I'm still not getting anything.